# Как изменить цвет кнопок в bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

В bootstrap.css поменял цвет кнопки btn-primary в различных состояних, но почему-то в состоянии hover она выделяется только наполовину. Где это исправить можно? Спасибо.

Comment: для изменения тем bootstrap используйте less

Comment: Можно сделать кастомные стили через сайт http://stylebootstrap.info/

Answer (score 2):

Вы поступили неправильно, нельзя менять в `bootstrap.css` ничего, для того, чтобы сделать по-человечески, вам нужно было ниже подключения файла бутстрапа вставить ссылку на свой файл стилей и переопределить в нём цвет кнопки. Нужно было указать состояние не только для базовых стилей, нужно было также указать цвета для как минимум *hover, focus, visited*.

Например:

```
.btn-primary{

background-color: red;

color: white;

}

.btn-primaru:hover,

.btn-primary:focus,

.btn-primary:visited{

background-color: green;

color: white;

}
```

Comment: а также можно было добавить этой кнопке свой класс, и в нем указать желаемые цвета, разумеется что ваш файл со стилями должен быть подключен после файла бутстрапа